# Not able to clear or save in SharedPreferences in Android Project

Tags: java, android

Saving code in Login.java activity :

```
 SharedPreferences preferences =getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 preferences.edit().putString("token", token).commit();
```

Deleting code in MainActivity.java class :

```
  SharedPreferences preferences =getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  preferences.edit().remove("token").commit();
```

It works if I stop the app or close it completely and then restart it. But it doesn't work otherwise.

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: Try `apply()` instead of `commit()`.

Comment: Tried that, didnt work. These codes are in two different activity classes btw.

Comment: It works if I stop the app or close it completely and then restart it. But it doesn't work otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `commit()` method, which immediately writes changes to the disk and may fail, you can use the `apply()` method for more reliable results. Unlike `commit()`, `apply()` writes changes asynchronously in the background without blocking the main thread. It returns immediately, without indicating whether the operation was successful or not.

By using `apply()`, you can ensure that changes to `SharedPreferences` are reliably saved, even if the app is not fully stopped or closed before restarting it.

Keep in mind that changes made with `apply()` may not be immediately reflected when retrieving preferences in the same execution sequence. If you need to guarantee the immediate removal of the token before performing subsequent actions, you may need to implement additional logic or callbacks to handle the timing appropriately.